Payment options - pay in full now or pay X for the next Y months
We are doing an event with two payment options:

pay in full now
pay X per month for the next Y months

I've looked through StackExchange and have found this question asked previously but from 5 years ago.  Five years is a long time, so I wonder if the situation has changed at all.
In the answer from 5 years ago, the best option was to use WebForm CiviCRM.  We would prefer to use a more native-to-Civi option.  So...

Can native CiviCRM with no Drupal-Webform do this now?
Can formbuilder do this?

I think the answer to both questions is "no" but wanted to check in with the community.
Thank you!

afaik FormBuilder isn't yet able to handle any payment
